# MySql Count duplicates of two combined fields

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, distinct

I need to count duplicates of two combined columns in MySql.

So for example data looks like this

```
Id, Name, Address
1, Hary, Street 1
2, Hary, Street 2
3, Hary, Street 1
```

So results would be
count, Name, Address

```
2 Hary, Street 1
1 Hary, Street 2
```

Comment: This is a basic `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` query. You can list multiple columns in `GROUP BY` and it will combine them when counting.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt, Name, Address
FROM <table>
GROUP BY Name, Address
```